# Populating search result in HTML table from JSON response in jQueryUI for c# webservice

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-ajax

**Scenario:** User enters a name into a `Textbox` and result is presented through `jQueryUI` `$("#textboxElement").autocomplete({...})`. User selects one of the suggested result (Full Name (username)) and that gets displayed into the `#textboxElement`. User now clicks on a `button` named "Permission" which should return a list of permission for the selected user populated into a pre-existing HTML table. Button click should takes user selection, extract only the last username between two parentheses and pass as a parameter for webservice that returns list of Permission object.

**Problem:** Nothing happens on the page. No error is shown. Other jQUeryUI user controls are all over the page and does not work. Even search does not work with other button click events on the page. [The Ajax code gives error (Unexpected ".)](http://jsfiddle.net/unyRV/5/) Where am I doing things wrong?

**jQueryUI** code:

```
    $("#showPermission")
                        .button()
                        .click(function () {

                            var username = $('input:text[name=nameSearch]').val();
                            //extracting a string of text that lies between two (parenthesis) from the end of the string
                            var result = username.split('(');
                                for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
                                   $("#txtSelectedUsername").val(result[i].split(')')[0]);
                                }
                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        url: "Search.aspx/GetUserPermission",
                                        data: "{'username':'" + $("#txtSelectedUsername").val() + "'}",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (data) 
                                                    {
                                                        $.each(data, function(key, val) 
                                                        {
                                                                var row = $("<tr />");
                                                                $("<td />").text(val.username).appendTo(row);
                                                                $("<td />").text(val.level).appendTo(row);
                                                                $("<td />").text(val.location).appendTo(row);
                                                                $("<td />").text(val.role).appendTo(row);

                                                                row.appendTo("table.usersPermissionTbl");

                                                         });​
                                                    },
                                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                                            {
                                                var errorMessage = "Ajax error: " + this.url + " textStatus: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown + "  xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText + " xhr.status: " + xhr.status;
                                                alert(errorMessage);
                                                    if (xhr.status != "0" || errorThrown != "abort") 
                                                    {
                                                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                                                    }
                                            }
                                        });//end of ajax 


                         });//end of click event
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="usersPermissionTbl" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Role</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**C# code**

```
public static Permission[] GetUserPermission(string username)
    {
        List<Permission> allPermission = new List<Permission>();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        string sqlString = "SELECT username, level, location, role from URTable WHERE username = '" + username + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter sadp = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlString, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sadp.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in table.Rows)
            {
                Permission permission = new Permission();
                permission.userName = dtrow["username"].ToString();
                permission.level = dtrow["level"].ToString();
                permission.location = dtrow["location"].ToString();
                permission.role = dtrow["role"].ToString();
                allPermission.Add(permission);
            }
        }

        con.Close();
        return allPermission.ToArray();

    }

    public class Permission
    {
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your fiddle has no html...

Comment: Have you marked the method as WebMethod?

Comment: @Saranya you are right. I found that WebMethod marking was missing. Added it.

Comment: posted it in answer so that this query will move to answered..

Comment: Indeed that was one of the problem but [WebMethod] is not only the solution. However I have solved this issue and I must add my solution to this Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark the method in aspx as **WebMethod**..

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

1. The following was missing on the C# method as @Saranya has mentioned.

   ```
   [WebMethod]
   [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
   ```
2. Binding to a table was wrong, so the solution is as below

   ```
   success: function (data) {
             var row;
             $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
             row = '<tr>';
             row += '<td>' + value.userName + '</td>';
             row += '<td>' + value.level + '</td>';
             row += '<td>' + value.location + '</td>';
             row += '<td>' + value.role + '</td>';
             row += '</tr>';
             $(row).appendTo("#usersPermissionTbl");
           });
   ```
3. String extraction was assiging the result to a textbox which should have been to a variable.

   ```
   var username = $('input:text[name=nameSearch]').val();
                                var name
                           var result = username.split('(');
                           for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
                               name = result[i].split(')')[0];
                           }
   ```